# Append dictionary to json response

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I want to append dictionary to json response output

**JSON response output:**

```
json_response= {
        "payload": [
            {
                "type": "type1",
                "id": "0001",
                "code": "TWBE",
                "version": "20190719",
                "creationDate": "20190719"
            }]
    }
```

**Dictionary to append:**

```
new_dict = '{"metadata": { "version": 1,,"service": "web-client","module": "Catalog","occurredAt": "2019-09-06T12:56:19.627+02:00"}}'
```

**Expected output:**

```
  {
"metadata": { "version": 1,"service": "web-client","module": "Catalog","occurredAt": "2019-09-06T12:56:19.627+02:00"},

 "payload": [
                {
                    "type": "type1",
                    "id": "0001",
                    "code": "TWBE",
                    "version": "20190719",
                    "creationDate": "20190719"
             }]
}
```

I tried converting dict to list and appended the dictionary, but I want the output as dictionary. Is there anyway we can add dictionary to json?

```
   if type(json_response) is dict:
        json_response = [json_response]
    json_response.append(new_dict)
```

Comment: That "expected output" isn't valid JSON.

Comment: @user2357112 Sorry for that, I have updated expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `json_response`, notwithstanding its name, is a dictionary and not a json representation of a dictionary, which would be a string. But that's fine. You `new_dict` is an attempt to be a json string, but it is ill-formed. It is better to just have it as a dictionary:

```
json_response= {
        "payload": [
            {
                "type": "type1",
                "id": "0001",
                "code": "TWBE",
                "version": "20190719",
                "creationDate": "20190719"
            }]
    }

new_dict = {"metadata":  {"version": 1, "service": "web-client", "module": "Catalog", "occurredAt": "2019-09-06T12:56:19.627+02:00"}}

# "append" by merging keys:
json_response["metadata"] = new_dict["metadata"]
```

The above code is combining the two dictionaries by merging keys. If you care about the order of the keys, which is maintained for ordinary dictionaries in Python 3.6 and greater, then:

```
d = {}
d["metadata"] = new_dict["metadata"]
d["payload"] = json_response["payload"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`json_response.update(new_dict)`

if `new_dict` is a string like in your example, you may need to convert it to dict first:

```
import json
new_dict = json.load(new_dict)
```